# How to call a method from a class in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I made a class in qt the the following code is the header:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H


class Test {
public:
    Test();
    void coppy(int zahl);
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

The methods are initialized in the .cpp file:

```
#include "test.h"

int tata;
Test::Test()
{
}

void coppy(int zahl)
{
    tata = zahl;
}
```

And I want to call the coppy method in a second class when I press a button like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    Test *t = new Test();
    t->coppy(5);
}
```

But I always get the following error: undefined reference to `Test::coppy(int)'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That’s a linking error because you didn’t define the method `coppy` of `Test`, you only defined a function with that name. You forgot the `Test::` it has to be `void Test::coppy( int zahl) {`

Comment: Oh no so easy, ofcours you are right I didn't expectet such an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Test::coppy(int zahl)
{
    tata = zahl;
}
```

It must be in your cpp file.

And I suggest you to make int tata a class member

Comment: He wrote void coppy(int zahl), not void Test::coppy(int zahl)

Comment: Ha, you've definitely been more attendant than me... You might hint more clearly to the missing scope, though...

Comment: Ah, sorry. Probably I should.

Answer (score 2):

`void coppy(int zahl)` defines a new function in your .cpp file. The compiler doesn't see any relation between this function and `Test`'s `coppy` function. To define a `class` member function you need to use the full member name, including the `class` name. Try the following instead :

```
void Test::coppy(int zahl)
//   ^^^^ Add the class name here
{
    tata = zahl;
}
```